# How to display custom font correctly with utf-8 character on android 2.3

Tags: android, utf-8, fonts

I have use custom font(Trebuchet Ms, Georgia,..) in my android app. It displays utf-8 characters correctly in android 4.0, but in android 2.3 it will display wrong character.
Anyone has experiance with this problem. I have researched but find out nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Check in the AndroidManifest.xml that you have this at first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: In the androidManifest.xml already has this line. 
Do you have another suggest? Thanks

Comment: The OP asks about font display in a running app. Your answer is just about the encoding of the manifest for compiling purposes, this is a completly unrelated thing.